# Uploading contacts to new group

Tags: email

Is it possible to import a list of contacts (name and email address only) from a google spreadsheet to the database and start a new email group containing only those addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely - when you import Contacts -> you can specify during the last step whether or not you'd like to add these Contacts you are importing to a Group (or Create a new one). Make sure to go to the Manage Group screen to and Edit your Group to make sure it has is a Mailing list group; Then you can CiviMail the Contacts in that Group.